# C# Can you store the string format in a variable?

Tags: c#, string

I have,

```
string text = $"RiseTime: Avg: {AvgRise:F5}, Max: {MaxRise:F5}, Min: {MinRise:F5} \n ";
```

I would like to change the F5 formatting during runtime to maybe F6 of E4 or something else. How can I do this?

Comment: It's just parameters to [string.Format](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.format?view=net-5.0). Resharper can convert between the two styles if you have that.

Comment: I've tried 
var fmt = "F6";
$"RiseTime: Avg: {AvgRise:fmt}";

But it just outputs, "RiseTime: Avg: fmt"

Answer (score 4):

As Charlieface points out, you need to readjust how you do things. Instead of using the inline formatting, use string.format

```
int decimalPlaces= 5;
string fmt="RiseTime: Avg: {0:F" + decimalPlaces.ToString() + "}, Max: {1:F" + decimalPlaces.ToString() +"}, Min: {2:F"+ decimalPlaces.ToString() +"} \n ";
string result=string.format(fmt, AveRise, MaxRise, MinRise);
```

Obviously using this method you can change the variable "fmt" as needed.

Comment: Is there an easier way though? With this method I'd have to make a fmt string for every type of format and use a switch statement or similar. Is there a way to store the "F5" in a var? I tried doing this as the other poster suggested but it did not work.

Comment: What do you mean, every type of format? What exactly are you trying to accomplish? What decision making are you using to choose which format to display? The method above works. What "did not work" for you?

Comment: I'd like to switch the display from showing 5 decimals to 6 decimals or displaying the format in exponential depending on the values of the RiseTime. RiseTime could be in seconds or microsecond or anywhere in between.

Comment: You could do a format (`$""`) for the format. It's making my head hurt

Comment: You can build the fmt string as needed. I added a line for "decimalPlaces" as an example. You could even build fmt using another string.format

Answer (score 2):

you want to change the format of the the output number at runtime. Unfortunately you can not do it straightforward using string interpolation.

You need to call `ToString` method explicitly on the numbers and pass the format of choice to that method.

Consider following code.

```
public static void Main()
{
    //Example values of variables.
    float AvgRise = 103.4343383F;
    float MaxRise = 439.2323476F;
    float MinRise = 93.56494495F;
    
    // Choice of number format stored in a string variable.
    string numberFormat = "E4";
    
    // Approach 1 : Calling ToString method on numbers and store string output in variables.
    string avgRiseFormatted = AvgRise.ToString(numberFormat);
    string maxRiseFormatted = MaxRise.ToString(numberFormat);
    string minRiseFormatted = MinRise.ToString(numberFormat);
    // And use those variables in the final output string.
    string fmt = $"RiseTime: Avg: {avgRiseFormatted}, Max: {maxRiseFormatted}, Min: {minRiseFormatted}";

    Console.WriteLine(fmt);
    //Output : RiseTime: Avg: 1.0343E+002, Max: 4.3923E+002, Min: 9.3565E+001


    // Approach 2 : call the ToString method as part of the final output string.
    string text = $"RiseTime: Avg: {AvgRise.ToString(numberFormat)}, Max: {MaxRise.ToString(numberFormat)}, Min: {MinRise.ToString(numberFormat)}";

    Console.WriteLine(text);
    //Output : RiseTime: Avg: 1.0343E+002, Max: 4.3923E+002, Min: 9.3565E+001
}
```

With the above solution, you can assigned the format value `F5`, `F6` or `E4` to `numberFormat` variable at runtime and get the expected output.

I hope this will help you solve your issue.

Comment: I went with approach 2. This did it, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

just use three variables text1 with F5 and text2 with F6...
and choose every time the appropriate variable

Comment: This actually didn't work. It doesn't recognize the "F5", "F6", etc when putting it in a variable. It will just output, "RiseTime: Avg: text1" or :RiseTime: Avg: text2"